# Can blessings actually work?

Tags: biology, humans, anatomy

Bishops bless and send prayers to reinforce warriors.

In my world those +10 strength prayers work simply because motivational speeches/rituals can influence the brain of a person to think in different ways. And since our emotions are chemicals I'd imagine that the bishops would give some edibles that react to emotion chemicals in the brain and create a new reaction.

Let's say a bishop blessed you, to make you stronger when sending mortal souls to their eternal judgment.

The bishop also made you drink/eat something as a ritual. This edible has little to no effect by itself but when combined with the right chemicals in your brain you actually become stronger, way stronger.

Is this plausible? I don't much understand the blood-brain barrier so sorry if it sounds like a stupid idea.

Comment: Curiously, I have thought a lot about blessings/curses in the real-world recently: things that are verbally said that have lingering effects on a person. One curse I know of is "I don't like the way you laugh" - said when a person is laughing. That sentence will likely be recalled when the person next laughs, so it will steal their happiness multiple times. It is more effective if said between people with a solid relationship. Coming up with IRL blessings is harder, but they do exist. Just as with that curse, they are purely mental, situational and depend on mutual respect.

Comment: [Placebo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placebo) and [nocebo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nocebo) effects, [drugs and stimulants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doping_in_sport) :)? They're a pretty good starting point, depending on how you understand "this edible has little to no effect by itself but when combined with the right chemicals in your brain you actually become stronger, way stronger.".

Comment: I'm reminded of the scene in *Foundation* where a priest pronounces a curse on a fleet of ships.  I'm a bit fuzzy on the details, whether something in the curse triggered the failsafe mechanism to shut down the ships, or whether they had an accomplice activate it simultaneously (though given the setup, even that would have been a ritual they wouldn't have understood the details of) -- but it wouldn't be too hard to imagine the first being the case.

Answer (score 6):

## Warhammer 40,000 lore is built on it

The entire lore of W40k...

[image]

...is built on the notion that technology got so advanced that eventually humanity lost control over it, regressed to a more primitive state and — from that point on — essentially treated technology in a religiously reverent manner.

So in W40k, blessings *do* work, in that they are just normal operating procedures, done without knowing what they are actually for or having a full understanding what they should be.

---

Now, as an author you need to separate what is *realistic*, from what is *plausible*, from what is *credible*. These three things are similar, but separate. Your job is not to make it realistic, because that is usually quite *boring* and destroys the immersion...

[image]

*How to ruin [movie magic](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Comlink/Legends) with a Gillette Ladyshave and over-exposition*

...but to make it *credible*, you need to "sell" it to the audience and get them to accept your hand-wave of an explanation. You need forget "plausible", and aim for *credible*. If that then means inventing some kind of mechanism to make this happen —or ignoring the fine details that would make this impossible in real life — so much the better, because that adds flavour to your fictional world.

So, can it be made plausible?

Probably not, no, if you stick to pure biology and physics as we know it.

But if you invent some kind of mechanism / plot element — that in turn needs be neither realistic nor plausible, as long as it is *credible* — then you can do it.

---

### "So, what kind of plot element could that be?"

That could fill a whole book of possibilities, and thus falls outside the scope of this answer. I would need to know much more about your fictive world to answer that.

Comment: It's worth noting that the Warhammer 40K misses the goal of *credible* by a distance which would allow a fleet of imperial cruisers to fit in the middle. The lore of W40K only follows the rule-of-cool. If the OP doesn't want to warp the suspension of disbelief to beyond no author has ever gone before he should look for inspiration anywhere else.

Answer (score 6):

There is actually no need for *such* advanced technology - we had such chemicals for some time and they even [saw](https://www.standard.co.uk/culture/tvfilm/new-documentary-investigates-allied-drug-use-during-world-war-ii-a4223956.html) [use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-IX) [during](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_and_culture_of_substituted_amphetamines) WWII -  combined with the right state of mind [induced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propaganda_in_Nazi_Germany) by [charismatic individuals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolf_Hitler) makes wonders to your physical endurance.

Answer (score 5):

*The question, "Is this plausible?" is a difficult one here. This Stack is dedicated to helping you develop and consistently use the rules and systems of your fictional world. Since it's your world, you set the rules, so the answer to the question is always, "yes." (Questions asking if something is believable in the Real World are off-topic here.) If you are asking if the idea of a ritual combined with an edible resulting in something seemingly miraculous exceeds the threshold for suspension of disbelief? That's, "yes," too, and here's why:*

**Mexican Indian healing ceremonies**

The drug [Peyote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peyote) combined with ritual has been the center of various indigenous healing ceremonies for millennia.

> This is a healing ceremony, so during the ritual, everyone is to pray for the present individual who is ill.  Most often, this person has been undiagnosed.  This is their purpose for the ceremony.  Taking the peyote and participating in the meeting, their illness is supposed to be revealed to them so they may diagnose themselves.  This is the individual acting as the “self perceptible object”.  In an interview, a member of the Navajo tribe said, “But if someone else, maybe a road man is telling you, [prior to the ceremony], this is the problem this is what’s wrong, then you tend to not believe them.  It’s you, you got to work with your mind and your faith.  That’s all it takes.” ([Source](https://sites.coloradocollege.edu/indigenoustraditions/6-%E2%80%A2-independent-projects/peyote-in-native-american-traditions/))

**Norse Berserkers**

In this case, ritual is combined with [adrenaline](https://www.historyextra.com/period/viking/the-truth-about-viking-berserkers/) to bring about a state of powerful (and irresponsible) fury and conviction in battle.

> Viking warriors looked to the god Odin to give them aggression and courage in battle, but the berserkers took this a step further. According to the sources they could rout an outnumbering force, and when they attacked they howled like mad dogs or wolves. It was said that neither iron nor fire could injure them, and they didn’t know pain. After a battle they were as weak as infants, totally spent both physically and psychologically. ([Source](https://www.historyextra.com/period/viking/the-truth-about-viking-berserkers/))

The same is fundamentally true for the Maori use of the [Haka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haka), which serves the dual purpose of "psyching" out Maori warriors and causing fear in their enemies.

*And the idea has carried over into fiction so greatly that I doubt anyone would question your use of it. I'll give you the most famous case:*

**Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde**

> In early March, Jekyll's butler, Mr. Poole, visits Utterson and says Jekyll has secluded himself in his laboratory for weeks. Utterson and Poole break into the laboratory, where they find Hyde's body wearing Jekyll's clothes, apparently having killed himself. They find a letter from Jekyll to Utterson. Utterson reads Lanyon's letter, then Jekyll's. Lanyon's letter reveals his deterioration resulted from the shock of seeing Hyde drink a serum that turned him into Jekyll. Jekyll's letter explains he had indulged in unstated vices and feared discovery. He found a way to transform himself and thereby indulge his vices without fear of detection. Jekyll's transformed body, Hyde, was evil, self-indulgent, and uncaring to anyone but himself. Initially, Jekyll controlled the transformations with the serum, but one night in August, he became Hyde involuntarily in his sleep.  (Summary of *[Strange Case of Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_Case_of_Dr_Jekyll_and_Mr_Hyde)* (1886))

**Conclusion**

Absolutely, the premise you're working with to develop a rule for your world has basis in human history and is well known in the world of fiction and will therefore be more than adequate for suspension of disbelief.

Comment: Coincidentally related : [What tactical advantages can be gained from frenzied, berserkir units on the battlefield?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/193332/what-tactical-advantages-can-be-gained-from-frenzied-berserkir-units-on-the-bat). I personally like the comment "How is this not describing a real-world scenario?", hinting at how much it is believable :).

Answer (score 2):

It's your world, so you make the rules what is and isn't possible. Just make it somewhat consistent and keep the suspension of disbelief.

If your story is good people would eat anything, I mean watching several episodes of [screen rant pitch meetings](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL--PgETgAz5FGoatB9KQzbnpv0bgZqU2l) and [critical drinker](https://www.youtube.com/c/TheCriticalDrinker) will make explicit how much nonsense people are willing to tolerate in order to be entertained.

To every question why this happens, the answer is because the story could happen.